# Internal NuGet Server is unreachable

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I have setup an internal NuGet server to ensure that only approved versions of packages are deployed to our solutions but I am confused as to why I cannot download a specific package.

First, I check to see if the package exists on the NuGet server:

PM> Get-Package -Filter data -ListAvailable

```
Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes
--                             -------              -------------------------      
DataMatrix.net                 0.4.2                .[Removed]. 
EntityFramework                6.1.0                .[Removed]. 
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.0                .[Removed].
```

I then try and download the package

```
PM> Install-Package DataMatrix.Net
The source at My NuGet Server [http://url.to.nuget/nuget] is unreachable. 
Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at ...
```

I can see it is doing the lookup:

```
2014-08-27 13:10:01 172.16.1.123 GET /nuget/Search() $orderby=Id&$filter=IsLatestVersion&$skip=0&$top=30&searchTerm='data'&targetFramework=''&includePrerelease=false 80 - 10.1.10.100 NuGet+VS+PowerShell+Console/2.8.50313.46+(Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.1.7601+Service+Pack+1,+VS+Professional/12.0) 200 0 0 46
```

Yesterday, I installed a package from this server with no problems at all:

```
2014-08-26 16:27:15 172.16.1.123 GET /api/v2/package/pdfsharp.htmlrender/1.0.0 - 80 - 10.1.10.100 NuGet+VS+PowerShell+Console/2.8.50313.46+(Microsoft+Windows+NT+6.1.7601+Service+Pack+1,+VS+Professional/12.0) 200 0 0 59
```

I have also tried to goto the url of the package (http://nuget.server.url/api/v2/package/DataMatrix.Net/0.4.2) and this works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have just restarted the IDE and it appears to be working fine now - anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: If you need proxy settings to access external sources I've encountered problems accessing internal sources. There seems to be a conflict there in the nuget settings.

Comment: Hi @8DH - we don't use a proxy server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, adding `-Source http://location.to/nuget` appears to work but this situation is not ideal...